# Please help me identify this frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image][image] The sword on the frame is the only identifiable mark on the bike. A guy I used to rent a room to left all his crap here. It's been sitting in my garage for years.

Comment: Its some kind of stunt bike.   Totally lacks a front brake.  May have a coaster brake in the rear wheel (back pedal)  and the pegs are for grinding on things.   If former-boarder has abandoned it, its yours now.  Try riding it yourself, or give it to the local bike fixup co-op, or flog it off on ebay/CL/etc.  We can't guess what it might be worth, but "not a lot" would be right.  Or contact the guy and ask when he's coming to get his crap.

Comment: Fairly generic.  The most distinctive feature is the pseudo-lugging on the top and down tubes near the head tube.  I can't tell whether the headset is hollow, to facilitate a spin-around front brake cable.  If so that would indicate it's probably 5-10 years old.  If not, then probably older.

Comment: Most street bmx of about 10 years ago looked like this. Standard Primo pedals and cranks, brakeless which was just becoming a thing then, seat angled for barspins, but not yet micro gears or left hand drives. The Bounty Hunter thing nor sword ring any bells for me, maybe get a better picture of the red logo on the downtube? You're better of asking on bikeguide.org or ridemonkey.com forums, afaik 'oldtimers' still frequent those. In any case, I wouldn't call this crap: looks like a decent bike, will be hard to destruct, on the heavy side though compared to recent models.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I found out it is the Killing Machine by Solid Bikes. Not sure what year yet, but early 2000's

Comment: @djaquette you should post that as an answer, and then click the "accept" button to show that this question is solved.

Comment: The "pseudo-lugging" is called gusset and it's quite common in MTBs and BMXes.

Answer (score 3):

OP's answer-as-a-comment:

> I found out it is the Killing Machine by Solid Bikes. Not sure what year yet, but early 2000's

Answer (score 1):

The brake lug positions suggest approximately 2001-2003. Earlier versions had chain stay mounted brake lugs. With the event of smaller chainrings/gearing (classic 44/16 ratio down to 39/15 or 36/14) many frame makers started to put the lugs on the seat stays for better chain clearance.

Is this thing still in your possession?

Matt.

Comment: You don't actually mention a brand name and model name. Can you be more specific? Or is your advice generic to all BMX?

Comment: As previously mentioned by another member, Solid Bikes' Killing Machine. Solid Bikes were founded in Sacramento, California by Aaron Huff and Ryan Pucket. Their first frame offering was the Duke frame. A real heavy weight. The killing Machine was their second frame. A more all-rounder. Their third was the Wasp. Designed more for trails and ramps. They made all their own hardware and printed their own softgoods in-house. Headsets, cranks, sprockets, frames, stems, bars. FBM, T1 and a few other high end companies had products made by Solid. Their reputation was on another level.